# Adding CCPoint to CCArray

Tags: c++, ios, arrays, cocos2d-x

I'm looking to call up a random `CCPoint` from `CCArray`, and then remove that point from the array so that it's not called up again. This is the code I used:

```
    myArray->addObject(pos1);
```

Where `pos1` is a `CCPoint` and `myArray` is a `CCArray`. When I write that line, it brings up an error that reads: "No viable conversion from cocos2d::CCPoint to cocos2d::CCObject *". I know this means that `CCPoint` doesn't inherit from `CCObject`, but just making it inherit CCObject doesn't help the problem. I've also tried typecasting `pos1` as well but that doesn't work either. What do you suggest I do so that I can keep an array of points? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you take CCPoint[] array directly and store some static points and pop random CCPoint from it.

Comment: I didn't think of that. I'm calling up these points randomly though, and I want to make sure a single element (CCPoint) isn't used twice. How would I do that?

Comment: Yeah, you should take a static CCPoint array and take out the CCPoint from the array while calling and clear the index values of the array. So, that you may not get the same point again.

Comment: So to delete something at a certain index value, I have

CCPoint mySpecificPoint = myArray[rand()%4];

To remove whatever mySpecificPoint ended up being from the array, would I set it to NULL? I'm worried that could cause a problem after I add the sprite to the scene with that position: mySpecificPoint.

Comment: Of course, then you can create another new CCPoint and replace the new CCPoint in the random index. i.e., `int randIndex = rand()%4; CCPoint mySpecPoint = myArray[randIndex]; CCPoint newPoint = new CCPoint(rand()%randIndex, rand()%randIndex); myArray[randIndex] = newPoint;`
You could try this.

Comment: Why when making `newPoint`, you wrote `new CCPoint(rand()%randIndex, rand()%randIndex);`? Wouldn't you only need to write rand()%randIndex once?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56508/discussion-between-user1676682-and-shiva-kumar-ganthi).

Answer (score 1):

@Shiva Kumar Ganthi comments with C-arrays are all good, but I think that using `std::vector` would be better. The main improvement would be the fact, that you can always check how many elements a `vector` has, and you don't have to worry about setting a used element to NULL and then checking for it when you take another random position (which can prove dangerous with big arrays that have a lot of `NULL`s).

Also learning about standard containers is also beneficial.

Oh, on a side note : you don't have to use `CCPoint *`, `CCPoint` is just fine.